# Correct form error response code?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have a custom error message that get sent back to the user if the form validation does not pass, like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'data' => [
            'errors' => $validator->messages()
        ],
    ], 400);
}
```

I'm just wondering what the correct error response code is for invalid form data. Currently I have it set to `400`, but I don't know if this is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation) docs, `... a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user ....` 
, so I would say `422 - Unprocessable Entity` error code is the most appropriate.